# How to simulate dipolar magnetic toruses floating in zero gravity?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

So I'm trying to simulate the interaction in a zero gravity environment between dipolar magnetic rings (toruses), the magnetic poles being located on each side of the plane of the torus so that, when they attract, they form a stack. Ideally, I also want to be able to animate the scale of the rings during the simulation, without impacting object rigidity. Any suggestions of how to do this?

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.